# How can i implement const in Boost Spirit?

Tags: c++, compiler-construction, grammar, boost-spirit

I am interested in Boost Spirit nowadays and trying to build something. Can we implement  something like a const in C++ using Spirit? For instance, user will define an item like;

```
constant var PROG_LANG="Java";
```

"constant var" seems weird, I accept but you got the idea. I searched the internet but can't found anything about it.

Comment: You **do know** there's a `const` keyword in C++, right?

Comment: of course i know and how is this related to this question? How can i implement the constants in my small language?

Comment: @userXXX Ah so you are asking about your own language! In this cass, just implement a check in the compiler which prohibits assignments to `const` values.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What the BigBoss said :)

Only I'd do without the semantic actions - making it far less... verbose (See also [Boost Spirit: "Semantic actions are evil"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8259440/boost-spirit-semantic-actions-are-evil/8259585#8259585)):

```
vdef = 
    ("constant" >> attr(true) | attr(false)) >>
    "var" >> identifier >> '=' >> identifier_value >> ';' ;
```

That's all. This uses `qi::attr` to account for the default (missing `constant` keyword).

Here's a full demo with output:

http://liveworkspace.org/code/c9e4bef100d2249eb4d4b88205f85c4b

Output:

```
parse success: 'var myvariable = "has some value";'
data: false;myvariable;has some value;
parse success: 'constant var myvariable = "has some value";'
data: true;myvariable;has some value;
```

Code:

```
#include <boost/fusion/adapted.hpp>
#include <boost/spirit/include/qi.hpp>
#include <boost/spirit/include/karma.hpp>

namespace qi    = boost::spirit::qi;
namespace karma = boost::spirit::karma;
namespace phx   = boost::phoenix;

struct var_definition {
    bool is_constant;
    std::string name;
    std::string value;

    var_definition() : is_constant( false ) {}
};

BOOST_FUSION_ADAPT_STRUCT(var_definition, (bool, is_constant)(std::string, name)(std::string, value))


void doParse(const std::string& input)
{
    typedef std::string::const_iterator It;

    qi::rule<It, std::string()> identifier, identifier_value;
    qi::rule<It, var_definition(), qi::space_type> vdef;

    {
        using namespace qi;

        identifier_value = '"' >> lexeme [ +~char_('"') ] > '"';
        identifier       = lexeme [ +graph ];
        vdef             = 
            ("constant" >> attr(true) | attr(false)) >>
            "var" >> identifier >> '=' >> identifier_value >> ';' ;
    }

    var_definition data;

    It f(std::begin(input)), l(std::end(input));
    bool ok = qi::phrase_parse(f,l,vdef,qi::space,data);
    if (ok)   
    {
        std::cout << "parse success: '" << input << "'\n";
        std::cout << "data: " << karma::format_delimited(karma::auto_, ';', data) << "\n";
    }
}

int main()
{
    doParse("var myvariable = \"has some value\";");
    doParse("constant var myvariable = \"has some value\";");
}
```

Comment: thanks for your reply, sehe. i will apply this after i arrive home and then accept your answer. you are answering my 2nd question in spirit. (i can't look at spirit because of assignments everyday) i wish i could vote 5 times up. thanks again.

Comment: and how did you becoma a spirit expert? i read all the qi documentation and i am looking at examples but i am having hard times understanding examples? do you have any suggestions?

Comment: @user1662800 I learned, basically, by reading the documentation _when I needed it_. And then I did a lot of exercises (basically, using Spirit for my every parsing need, even if it wasn't the best fit). I should admit I never paid any attention to the examples, so I don't know how 'hard' they are.

Comment: @sehe, a couple of questions if I may... 1) will the parser for identifier_value eat whitespace after the opening (and before the closing) quote? If that's undesirable then we just widen the lexeme[]? 2) What does that tilde '~' character do? I can't find documentation for it in the Spirit docs.

Comment: @PeteUK the whitespace will be properly included. If anything, the `lexeme` is redundant here, because the rules (`identifier`, `identifier_value`) are declared _without a skipper_. Good catch, in that respect. The documentation for `~` is here [Expression Semantics](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/libs/spirit/doc/html/spirit/qi/reference/char/char.html#spirit.qi.reference.char.char.expression_semantics)

Comment: @sehe of course - the lack of skipper! Thank you for the expression semantics link. I understand the ~ now.

Answer (score 1):

I don't get your question correctly, `spirit` is a parser and it has nothing to do with the meaning of `constant` it can only parse it, but if you mean parse an optional variable like `constant` then it can be something line:

```
namespace qi = boost::spirit::qi;
namespace phx = boost::phoenix;

typedef std::string::const_iterator it;
struct var_definition {
    bool is_constant;
    std::string name;
    std::string value;
    var_definition() : is_constant( false ) {}
};
qi::rule<it, std::string()> identifier;
qi::rule<it, std::string()> identifier_value;
qi::rule<it, var_definition(), boost::spirit::ascii::space_type> vdef;

void mark_var_as_constant(var_definition& vd) {vd.is_constant=true;}
void set_var_name(var_definition& vd, std::string const& val) {vd.name=val;}
void set_var_value(var_definition& vd, std::string const& val) {vd.value=val;}

vdef %=
    -qi::lit("constant")[phx::bind(mark_var_as_constant, qi::_val)] >>
    qi::lit("var") >>
    identifier[phx::bind(set_var_name, qi::_val, qi::_1)] >>
    qi::char_('=') >>
    identifier_value[phx::bind(set_var_value, qi::_val, qi::_1)] >>
    qi::char_(';');
```

Of course there are other ways, for example:

```
(qi::lit("constant")[phx::bind(mark_var_as_constant, qi::_val)] | qi::eps)
```

And the easiest is:

```
qi::hold[ qi::lit("constant")[phx::bind(mark_var_as_constant, qi::_val)] ]
```

Comment: Your `vdef` rule has a problem: both the `char_` expressions should be literals, and/or the normal rule assignment (`operator=` instead of _auto-rule_ `operator%=`) should be used. (See my answer for a more succinct way to write this without all the manual binding with phoenix).