# Boost Spirit Qi Custom Syntesized Attribute (Set a specific member of a struct attribute via a semantic action)

Tags: c++, attributes, boost-spirit, boost-spirit-qi, synthesize

Suppose I have a structure that I want to parse into with Spirit Qi, that is defined as such:

```
struct data_
{
    bool export;
    std::wstring name;

    data_() : export(false) {}
};
```

Also, suppose the struct has been adapted to fusion like this:

```
BOOST_FUSION_ADAPT_STRUCT(
    data_,
    (bool, export)
    (std::wstring, name)
)
```

And the associated rule is:

```
qi::rule<Iterator, data_(), skipper<Iterator> > rule_data;

rule_data = -lexeme["SpecialText" >> !(alnum | '_')] [ boost::phoenix::at_c<0> = true ] // If this string is found, , set "export" to true
            > lexeme["Name" >> !(alnum | '_')] // this is supposed to go into the "name" member
```

This compiles, so far, so good. However, "name" stays empty now!

So essentially, I am asking: Given that "SpecialText" precedes "Name", how would I synthesize a boolean attribute for "export" properly, rather than a string?

**EDIT**
After pulling my hair out on this, I randomly stumbled upon the "matches[]" parser, which seems to do what I want.

Nonetheless, the question still exists in the general form, for example, if I wanted to return a certain string or other data type instead of a bool.
Essentially, how to set a specific member of a struct attribute via a semantic action.

Comment: You need to use `%=` operator if you want to combine semantic actions and auto attribute synthesis `rule_data %= ...`

Comment: See this: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_54_0/libs/spirit/doc/html/spirit/qi/reference/nonterminal/rule.html

Comment: Check this for how to set values in semantic actions: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/libs/spirit/phoenix/doc/html/phoenix/starter_kit.html#phoenix.starter_kit.values

Comment: Thanks! I was just about to ask where you found the %=, since it's not listed here: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_1/libs/spirit/doc/html/spirit/qi/quick_reference/qi_parsers/operator.html

Comment: @namezero it's a bit of a FAQ... sadly e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/a/17385379/85371

Comment: Another alternative that doesn't use semantic actions can be found [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13118424/2417774).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

How to set a struct member.

### Option 1 (`phx::bind`)

Given a struct `S`

```
struct S
{
    int         field1;
    std::string field2;
    int         target_field;
    bool        field3;
};
```

You can assign to a field (e.g. `target_field`) like so:

```
rule<It, S()> p = int_ [ phx::bind(&S::target_field, _val) = _1 ];
```

Now, you can make the `bind` more readable, by doing something like:

```
auto target_field_ = phx::bind(&S::target_field, _val);

p = int_ [ target_field_ = _1 ];
```

Proof of concept: **[live on Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/26e44f9449145141)**

```
#include "boost/spirit/include/qi.hpp"
#include "boost/spirit/include/phoenix.hpp"

namespace qi  = boost::spirit::qi;
namespace phx = boost::phoenix;
typedef std::string::const_iterator It;

struct S
{
    int         field1;
    std::string field2;
    int         target_field;
    bool        field3;
};

int main()
{
    const std::string input("42");
    It f(begin(input)), l(end(input));

    S instance;

    using namespace qi;
    rule<It, S()> p = int_ [ phx::bind(&S::target_field, _val) = _1 ];

    // or, alternatively:
    auto target_field_ = phx::bind(&S::target_field, _val);
    p = int_ [ target_field_ = _1 ];

    if (parse(f, l, p, instance))
        std::cout << "Parsed: " << instance.target_field;
}
```

## Option 2 (fusion sequences)

You can treat a struct as a fusion sequence by using *adaptation*:

```
#include "boost/fusion/adapted/struct.hpp"

BOOST_FUSION_ADAPT_STRUCT(S, (int, field1)(std::string, field2)(int, target_field)(bool, field3))
```

Now you can use phoenix *lazy* functions on these sequences in your semantic action:

```
rule<It, S()> p = int_ [ phx::at_c<2>(_val) = _1 ];
```

I don't prefer this style (because it 'degrades' an expressive struct to ... a tuple of sorts), but it might come in handy. **[Live on Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/eaa27e9cb23e0136)**

Comment: Forgive me, but isn't Option 2 exactly what I had above?

Comment: Ok, I see in option 1 we're binding the constructor of target_field to _val and assigning the attribute. So, [ phx::bind(&S::field2, _val) = "lalaland" ] should be a valid semantic action, then, too, correct? Would this interfere with automatic attribute propagation over the other fields, then?

Comment: @namezero Erm, yes, it would appear so :/ Lol. That's a strong case for formatting your code for SO then (it was past the "right margin"). Anyways, I reckoned "auto rules" answered your real question, so I just quickly picked up the "How to set a struct member" loose end...

Comment: @namezero Yes, semantic actions _always_ interfere with attribute propagation. *But* you can simultaneously use **`%=`** for _auto-rule_ behaviour and _assign to `qi::_1` in the semantic action instead...?

Comment: Ok, that is great to know. I will use the auto-rule from now on whenever a semantic action is present in the rule (and I wish to keep the normal attribute propagation). I get it now why only the field set with at_c<>() was filled, and nothing else!

Comment: At least the mental trigger to think about it.  Honestly, most often when I use a semantic action I don't want automatic attribute propagation (either because there isn't an attribute or because the  construction is non trivial). I tend to avoid semantic action on the whole.

Comment: Yes, that's why I was excited to find the matches[] parser. But then I became curious about how to do it in general, short of a custom parser, which I saw is possible, too.